# Incorrect version of jest trying to run jest

Tags: jestjs

I have jest tests in my angular project.

I have a package.json file specifying the version of jest I would like to use to run the test. The file includes:

```
"@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"jest-preset-angular": "^7.1.1",
```

The jest config also includes:

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
  "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"
],
```

This is where the issue occurs. When trying to run `jest`, I get the following message:

```
● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "setupFilesAfterEnv" with value ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"] was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

Configuration Documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

I had a look at `jest -h` and found a flag which gives me the setup of the jest environment.

```
jest --showConfig
```

This however shows that I am running jest on version

```
"version": "23.6.0"
```

So my question lies here. How come after I do an `npm i`, the jest version trying to run the tests is different / old.

I tried installing jest-cli with the `-g` flag and the `save-dev` flag.

Also trying to run tests in VS Code, if thats any help.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Full log of `npx jest --showConfig`

```
● Validation Warning:

  Unknown option "setupFilesAfterEnv" with value ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"] was found.
  This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "/var/folders/bs/wrvrgl6132df8l5ndxv40m3m0000gn/T/jest_dx",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/",
        "setup-jest.ts"
      ],
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "detectOpenHandles": false,
      "errorOnDeprecated": false,
      "filter": null,
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globals": {
        "ts-jest": {
          "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$",
          "astTransformers": [
            "jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer"
          ]
        }
      },
      "haste": {
        "providesModuleNodeModules": []
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "html",
        "js",
        "json"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": [
        [
          "@app/(.*)",
          "/Users/name/Projects/project/src/app/$1"
        ],
        ...
      ],
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "6caa4...",
      "prettierPath": "/Users/name/Projects/project/node_modules/prettier/index.js",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "resolver": null,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "/Users/name/Projects/project",
      "roots": [
        "/Users/name/Projects/project"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": null,
      "skipFilter": false,
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "/Users/name/Projects/project/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen/build/index.js",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)"
      ],
      "testRegex": "",
      "testRunner": "/Users/name/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$",
          "/Users/name/Projects/project/node_modules/ts-jest/dist/index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": false,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": null,
    "coverageDirectory": "/Users/name/Projects/project/coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": null,
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "detectOpenHandles": false,
    "errorOnDeprecated": false,
    "expand": false,
    "filter": null,
    "globalSetup": null,
    "globalTeardown": null,
    "listTests": false,
    "maxWorkers": 7,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "always",
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "projects": null,
    "rootDir": "/Users/name/Projects/project",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "skipFilter": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": null,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "23.6.0"
}
```

Showing `npm config get` log here too:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://.../.../npm-group/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.9.0 node/v10.15.3 darwin x64"

; project config /Users/user/Projects/project/.npmrc
registry = "http://.../.../npm-group/"

; node bin location = /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/user/Projects/project
; HOME = /Users/user
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Comment: When you run `jest --showConfig` you are actually running the globally installed `jest`. If you want to check your locally install jest, you need `npx jest --showConfig`.

Comment: @seanplwong thanks for the reply. I ran that and that is `"version": "23.6.0"` also. :(

Comment: try `rm -r node_modules` and reinstall?

Comment: @seanplwong tried that too. I tried deleting the package-lock.json also and then re-installing. Version trying to run tests is still `23.6.0`. Is there a way to delete or uninstall or upgrade my globally installed jest version and install the newest?

Comment: to update global jest `npm i -g jest`, this will usually do. or try uninstalling it with `npm un -g jest` and then install it. Most likely you don't need jest globally, just `npm un -g jest`

Comment: @seanplwong ok so I uninstalled jest globally, but now I can't run jest at all. `Unknown command`. I tried uninstalling jest and jest-cli, then installing a correct version that i need `npm i -g jest-cli@24.9.0`. If I add jest-cli to my package.json it seems to work. But my other colleges don't have this problem so I don't want to be adding another library to the project.

Comment: can u put together a minimum reproducible repo?

Comment: please also dump info from `npm config get`, rmb to mask sensitive info

Comment: @seanplwong I can try putting together a repo to reproduce. Not sure of I can but I will try. I have other projects this happens in on my machine, but only seems to be happening to me, not my team members. I have dumped the `showConfig` output in the question above.

Comment: @seanplwong dumped result of `npm config get` into the question too

Comment: have you tried to use `https://registry.npmjs.org/` for registry instead? and retry in a clean repo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after a long search I've tried this:

```
type jest
```

Which gave me the location:

```
/usr/local/bin/jest
```

Renaming this file (or deleting it), solved the problem (note that now running `jest` will give `command not found`).

Comment: I actually never found the solution. I've migrated to a new laptop now and no longer have an issue with this.

Comment: I thought it's not going to be useful for you, but maybe for someone else (or my future self:)